# font-size is not responsive after changing px to rem

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-variables, css-calc

After being inspired from this [Pen By Dannie Vinther](https://codepen.io/dannievinther/pen/GNExxb?editors=1100) that shows how to make fonts responsive without using `media queries`, I decided to make another [Pen](https://codepen.io/inullpointer/pen/vvMwMO?editors=1100), but using `rem` as Dannie Vinther's pen uses `px`. I made some changes, but it does not working.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  /* Setting root font size*/
  --root-size: 20px;
  font-size: var(--root-size, 20px);
  /* Typography */
  --main-font: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  /* Calculation, Ranges from 421px to 1199px */
  --responsive: calc((var(--min-font) * var(--root-size)) + (var(--max-font) - var(--min-font)) * ((100vw - 420px) / (1200 - 420)));
}

h1 {
  /* Set max and min font sizes */
  --max-font: 2.5;
  /* 2.5rem equals to 50px */
  --min-font: 1.25;
  /* 1.25rem equals to 25px */
  font-family: var(--main-font);
  font-size: var(--responsive);
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  /* Set max and min font sizes */
  --max-font: 1;
  /* 1rem equals to 25px */
  --min-font: 0.7;
  /* 0.7rem equals to 14px */
  font-size: var(--responsive);
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  h1,
  p {
    font-size: calc(var(--max-font) * var(--root-size));
  }
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  h1,
  p {
    font-size: calc(var(--min-font) * var(--root-size));
  }
}


/* Whatever */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  padding: var(--root-size);
}

a,
a:visited,
a:focus,
a:active,
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}

a {
  color: skyblue;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out color;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  margin: .3em 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <h1>Responsive text with CSS Custom Properties</h1>
  <p>Custom Properties <a rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" href="http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables">isn't supported</a> by IE.</p>
  <p>Inspired From <a href="https://codepen.io/dannievinther/pen/GNExxb?editors=1100">A PEN BY Dannie Vinther</a></p>
</div>
```

In my code, `font-size` is almost constant. It changes on `720px`. `font-size` become equals to `50px`, when the screen `width` is more than or equals to `720px`. And `25px` when the screen `width` is less than `720px`. Only little change in `font-size` is observed when  the screen `width` decreases from `720px` to `420px`.

I'm unable to figure out the root cause. Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: One problem is that you define `--root-size: 20px` and then go on working on the idea that `1rem` is `20px`, but you never set the font-size of the html element.

Comment: @MrLister I think the rem part is irrelevant in this case because the issue remain the same. I think the title should be changed as it's missleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula isn't correct. If we consider this part: `((100vw - 420px) / (1200 - 420))` we will have `0px` when 100vw is equal to 420px and `1px` when equal to 1200px. Then you multiply by `(var(--max-font) - var(--min-font))` which is equal to `1.25` for the `h1` so basically you will have a value between `0px` and `1.25px` and if we add the main part  (`(var(--min-font) * var(--root-size))`) we will have a `font-size` between `25px` and **only** `26.25px` not `50px`.

You are missing the multiplication by `var(--root-size)` in the second part. Doing so you will have a value between `0px` and `25px` BUT there is an issue because you cannot do this multiplication since you will have `px*px` which is invalid using `calc`.

To overcome this, your `font-size` need to be defined uniteless and your fomula need to be adjusted like below:

```css
* {
  /* Setting root font size*/
  --root-size: 20;
  font-size: calc(var(--root-size, 20) * 1px);
  /* Typography */
  --main-font: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  /* Calculation, Ranges from 421px to 1199px */
  --responsive: calc((var(--min-font) * var(--root-size) * 1px) + (var(--max-font) - var(--min-font)) * var(--root-size) * ((100vw - 420px) / (1200 - 420)));
}

h1 {
  /* Set max and min font sizes */
  --max-font: 2.5;
  /* 2.5rem equals to 50px */
  --min-font: 1.25;
  /* 1.25rem equals to 25px */
  font-family: var(--main-font);
  font-size: var(--responsive);
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  /* Set max and min font sizes */
  --max-font: 1;
  /* 1rem equals to 25px */
  --min-font: 0.7;
  /* 0.7rem equals to 14px */
  font-size: var(--responsive);
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  h1,
  p {
    font-size: calc(var(--max-font) * var(--root-size) * 1px);
  }
  body {
   background:red;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  h1,
  p {
    font-size: calc(var(--min-font) * var(--root-size) * 1px);
  }
  body {
   background:blue;
  }
}


/* Whatever */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  margin: auto;
  padding: var(--root-size);
}

a,
a:visited,
a:focus,
a:active,
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}

a {
  color: skyblue;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out color;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  margin: .3em 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <h1>Responsive text with CSS Custom Properties</h1>
  <p>Custom Properties <a rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank" href="http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables">isn't supported</a> by IE.</p>
  <p>Inspired From <a href="https://codepen.io/dannievinther/pen/GNExxb?editors=1100">A PEN BY Dannie Vinther</a></p>
</div>
```